# How to enable remote desktop view in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vnc

I am trying to connect to a tight VNC server for remote desktop view. Its working fine when VNC server is running in XP PC but I am not able to connect remotly when VNC server is running in windows 7 PC. I am also able to connect to localhost in windows 7. I have turn off windows fire wall and other anti virus.

Answer (score 0):

So you can access the computer remotely when the firewall and antivirus are off?
In that case just add exceptions to the firewall and antivirus(not sure why the anitvirus would prevent you from accessing it, unless it includes a firewall and you shouldn't have 2 firewalls running at the same time) for the tight VNC server.

Also are you accessing the computer over the internet (through a router)? You need to forward ports to the Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the Remote Desktop Connector feature in Windows 7, please see the following link for further information: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: You can answer questions without making it a regular advertisement for your own place. Also, you have a profile, no need to repeat your signature every time.